# Shared prefs, how can I create one with a name fileNames?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have read that you can create more that one shared pref file, but I don't know how. This is how I normally use shared prefs.

```
SharedPreferences get;
SharedPreferences.Editor save;

get = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
save = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
```

This makes the file named `package.name_preferences.xml`. So how can I create the file `package.name_fileNames.xml` and how I write and read from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) on the activity instead of using the preference manager.

Comment: But how do I create it? I tried with this: `get = getSharedPreferences("fileNames", this.MODE_PRIVATE); save = get.edit();` but its not creating it.